# Jquery ajaxFileUpload not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

Experts,

I use ajaxFileUpload for my image upload. I created an API using codeigniter to do the image cropping and save the image to the server and return a xml response. I configure the ajaxFileupload to use the API and it works just fine in Firefox and other browsers but not in IE.

The ajaxFileUpload always returns success but it doesn't give me the xml response. When I checked the HTTP response using Firebug in Firefox, I can see the XML response and it is a valid XML. When I tried to parse the XML in IE it just give me 'undefined'.

I doubt that this is related to the PHP version or the Jquery version I'm using but correct me if there is a possibility. Anyone has experienced this before? Please let me know what is the best way to solve this...or please share if you guys have done ajaxfileupload with XML and could make it work in all major browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ajaxfileuplad in IE only receives the response which is declared as text/html or text/plain. So send a HTTP header to declare the response as text/html maybe effective.

ajaxfileupload processes the  reponse in the following steps:

1. target the response to a iframe ( In IE, only the content declared as text/html or text/plain could be targeted to a iframe)
2. call the response callback function defined in the ajaxfileupload, which converts the content in the iframe to the content-type specified in your settings for ajaxfileupload
3. call your response callback function in your settings for ajaxfileupload

Comment: Great, I had the same problem and setting the response type to "text/plain" solved it. Thanks!